# Cannot read properties of undefined although my if statement also checks if it is undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeerror

I get `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'latestDocDate')` with this:

```
if (this.state.latestDocDate === undefined || this.props.docRow[0].docDate > this.state.latestDocDate) {
```

There is a possibility `this.state.latestDocDate` could be undefined but I thought `this.state.latestDocDate === undefined` might cater for that. How do I resolve this?

Comment: `this.state` is undefined, evaluating the left-hand side fails _before_ comparison. Check for that first. Read up on optional chaining, if that's available in your runtime.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detecting an undefined object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property)

Comment: Also you can use null safe: `this.state?.latestDocDate`